# How to browse a folder in the same directory as the application

Tags: c#, browser, directory

[Screenshot of Solution](http://qwertyuiop1234567890.com/img/howto.png)

Just wondering in c#, if i set a folder as in the picture /img, now how do i read the image from this folder, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your solution is a WinForm Application

as for example loading image to PictureBox

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("img\\image_file_name.jpg");
```

To know the absolute path of that folder u can do something like

```
string img_folder_path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"img");
string path_to_image = System.IO.Path.Combine(img_folder_path, "image_filename.jpg");
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path_to_image);
```

Comment: guess my problem was i didnt place the image into my debug folder, however i have fixed it , thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the Copy to output directory property of the file under the img directory and set it to Copy if newer you can access the file directly, like

`Image.FromFile("img\image.png")`

[image]